# Search from String?

Tags: android, string, android-edittext

I have an application that I am trying to get to got to a specific part of a website. When the user enter the text inside of the `EditText` and hits the `Button` I want the application to take that string and enter it into the specific part of the url that I want it to go into.

**First Activity**

```
private EditText text;
private Button   search;


text = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.text);
search = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Search);

search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent (FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("string", text.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**Second Activity**

```
WebView mWebView;
private EditText  string;
private String string1;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    string = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.string);
    string.(getIntent().getExtras().getString("string"));        
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/"+string);


}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there.

```
string1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("string", "");
```

Later edit: the name of the `String` variable is `string1`, not `string`. You have to change your last line, too:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/"+string1);
```

Consider using less confusing, more descriptive variable names. It will help a lot on the long run.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am getting an error not on the `.getString` it is giving me three suggestions `remove argument to match getString(string)` , `change to getLong(...)`, and `change to putString`. Any suggestions on what I should do.

Comment: What exactly is the error? The method's signature is `getString(String key, String defaultValue)`. You could use instead `getString(String key)`, but you have to explicitly check for `null`, in case the bundle did not contain the key.

Comment: My bad, I had `("string")` as the string key in the first activity and string as the `EditText` in the Second activity so it must have been conflicting so I changed one of them an it works great. Thanks for your help.